# Change quarantine time on Ironmail

Tags: mcafee, email

Is it possible to change the time mails are kept in quarantine on an ironmail?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to find the exact spot in the manual, but reading through https://kc.mcafee.com/resources/sites/MCAFEE/content/live/PRODUCT_DOCUMENTATION/22000/PD22431/en_US/meg_672_ag_7002195A00_en-us.pdf has lots of useful tips.